# .gitignore exclude files in directory but not certain directories

Tags: git, gitignore

```
application/cache/*
application/cache/folder/*
application/cache/folder/onemorefolder/*
```

This doesn't seem to be working. When I clone the project, there is no `"application/cache"` folder or `"application/cache/folder"` folder, etc...

I'd like if files in the cache folders weren't cached but folders were, so that the folders permissions transfer and exist.

Answer (score 225, accepted):

Git doesn't track folders, only files, so if you ignore everything in a folder, Git won't have anything to track. You can add a `.gitignore` file to each directory (`application/cache`, `application/cache/folder`, `application/cache/folder/onemorefolder/`) with the following contents:

```
*
!.gitignore
```

Then, you can add those directories, and only the `.gitignore` file in each directory will get added -- but this means the directories will now be tracked (i.e., created when cloning).

Comment: The .gitignore files used for this purpose can be empty.

Comment: They can be empty, if the folders are ignored by an upper `.gitignore` file. In this case, its exact my answer.

Comment: more sensible and simpler is to use a file named .gitkeep, then you don't have to place anything in the .gitignore file.

Comment: @kevpie There are other files in the folder and he doesn't want them to be tracked. If the .gitignore file is empty, those files will apparently be tracked.

Comment: with the same purpose, I use `.gitkeep` instead of `.gitignore`. it make more sense to me

Comment: This does not work. It causes subdirectories to be ignored.

Comment: @CommaToast: Add `!subdir` if you want a subdirectory to not be ignored.

Comment: This didn't work for git in Visual Studio. I had to add a line to the beginning of the file to make it work... New line / another pattern / comment, as long as it wasn't the first thing.

Answer (score 22):

Git doesn't track empty directories. Just add some empty placeholder files in the folders you want to be committed.

```
touch application/cache/.keep
git add -f application/cache/.keep
```

Do this also with each "empty" folders. Later you can ignore these files, they really only exists to make sure that git creates those directories on clone. The entries in `.gitignore` keeps others files within the folders from being tracked (unless you force it with `git add -f` ;)).

Answer (score 17):

There is another perhaps cleaner way to do this. Rather than having sub .gitignore files in the folders you want to keep. You can put this in the root .gitignore as follows:

```
application/cache/*
application/cache/folder/*
application/cache/folder/onemorefolder/*
!*.gitkeep
```

Now just create and commit empty .gitkeep files into the directories as listed above. The folder will then be tracked with those .gitkeep files but none of the contents will be tracked.

Comment: or just `!*.gitkeep` :)

Comment: The question was how to ignore the contents of the folders but keep the folders themselves. So I believe my answer stands and just having !*.gitkeep won't ignore the contents of the folders.

Answer (score 3):

you can put a .gitignore file in each of it (like mipadi said) or make something like that on your root .gitingnore file

```
/assets/*/
/assets/*.*
```

it works fine for me

Comment: This works, but only if the repo is using file extensions. Something like `root/LICENSE-FILE` will not be excluded.

Answer (score 3):

Visual Studio didn't like the accepted answer. I had to add a new line before the * to make it work.

```
# Ignore all files in this folder.
*
!.gitignore
```