# how to track one specified directory but ignore any things in it with git

Tags: git, gitignore, ignore

I have one directory named "ignore-folder" and I track it in git, but I want to ignore the files and directories in it, how should I edit the `.gitignore`?

Comment: `git` does not track directories/folders, only files. The presence of directories is implied from the file paths, but `git` does not store them as separate entities. Thus you cannot track an empty directory.

Comment: @twalberg good tip for the OP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a `.gitignore` to the directory that you want to be tracked, ignoring all files inside that dir.

Like so

```
# Ignore everything in this directory
*
# Except this file
!.gitignore
```

or if you want to be more specific, eg only csv files

`*.csv`

Also check "[.gitignore exclude files in directory but not certain directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5600621/gitignore-exclude-files-in-directory-but-not-certain-directories)"

Answer (score -1):

if you want to track the folder itself, but not the files in the folder, you should edit the .gitignore to say yourdirectoryname/*

If you want to ignore the directory as well, you can write yourdirectoryname/ in the .gitignore

Comment: I tried this, not working. This will ignore the directory together.