# .gitignore exclude directories under directory, but not top-level files

Tags: git, version-control, gitignore

I have a folder populated with both files (mostly archives) and non-specific sub-directories (their expansion) and want to ignore the extracted files. Files always extract to a sub-directory.

What should I add to my .gitignore ?

Comment: `*/` will entirely ignore only and all subdirectory content.

Answer (score 0):

Following [this question and its accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5600621/gitignore-exclude-files-in-directory-but-not-certain-directories), this snippet added to a *.gitignore* file within the directory in question will do:

```
*
!/*
*~
```

This ignores everything recursively from this directory, but not the files contained directly in it, except for files ending in ~ (emacs backups).